# Spring cloud stream with Rabbitmq: How to output message to the same exchange as the input exchange

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have such a stream app. The idea is whenever the app receives a message, it sends a message with same content but with 5s delay to the same exchange that it listens to. Below is the code. However I found that the delayed message bypass rabbitmq but instead it gets routed back to the app.

I also saw a warning `You seem to be sending data to the input binding.  It is not recommended, since you are bypassing the binder and this the messaging system exposed by the binder`

I figured that since I set both input and output to the same binding, the `streamBridge.send("test-app")` may sent to input that's why the message wasn't actually sent out.

I also tried creating another binding for output but that created a different exchange.

How do I make it so that `streamBridge.send` send message to the same exchange as the input binding?

app code

```
@Bean
fun testConsumer() = Consumer<Message<?>> {
  message ->
    streamBridge.send("test-app",  
        MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.payload)
          .setHeader("x-delay", 5000)
           .build())
}
```

stream config in application.yaml

```
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: testFunction
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          testConsumer-in-0: test-app
          testConsumer-out-0: test-app
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          test-app:
            consumer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              binding-routing-key: test-key
              delayed-exchange: true
            producer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              binding-routing-key: test-key
              delayed-exchange: true
      bindings:
        test-app:
          group: test-group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers don't "listen to" exchanges, they listen to a queue that is bound to an exchange with a routing key.

You can't specify both a producer and consumer on the same binding name.

Just make two bindings, with a different name, but pointing to the same destination.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, I will create another binding with name `test-app-out` for the output with the same configuration as the input, but having a property `test-app-out.destination=test-app`. This will route the output message to the same exchange `test-app` right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.